# Android: Show view in Landscape while application is in Portrait

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I have an Android application that is is locked in portrait mode at all times. However I want to show a view in fullscreen landscape mode without having the activity or the application in landscape mode. How can I have an xml for a view that is forced to be in landscape mode while the application is in portrait mode?

I don't want to do rotations in my code because I want to keep it simple and define the layout in xml. Also with different screen resolutions it might not work and alter my layout. But if this is the only solution, how can I do it?

Comment: Is the full screen landscape view visible at all when in portrait (for example, does it show a thumbnail in portrait and then full image in landscape)?

Comment: No, I detect the change to landscape using a OrientationEventListener and then do a slide from bottom to up animation to appear the fullscreenview.

Comment: can't you make xml in landscape..cause you want activity title bar on top like portrait and view like landscape..then make the view in xml as it look like in landscape and show it..

Comment: I didn't undestand your answer, but I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this through XML. In fact I don't think there's a straightforward solution. If you have something very simple, you can probably override the [`onDraw`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method, [rotate the Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29), and then draw the view. If you have more complicated behavior like scrolling then it'll end up being a lot of work.

Why do you want a view that fills the screen in landscape mode without the activity being in landscape? What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: My Activity is a TabActivity with 3 tabs. The behaviour I want is that when the user tilts the screen to landscape I want to show an animation of the scorecard view sliding from bottom to up (in this case since it is in landscape it has to come from left to right) and when he positions back to portrait it slides back down. It is something he will do quickly just to check the scores, I don't want the status bar to change to landscape nor to recreate my entire tabactivity. I just want to show a view on top of it, but in landscape. Is this so hard to do?

Comment: Yes unfortunately as far as I know, this is something fairly hard to do unless your scorecard view is very simple or custom drawn anyway.

Comment: Following your advise, I ended up creating a new landscape activity that was started when I tilted the device horizontally. Not really what I wanted to do, but reasonably enough.

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml. For example:

```
        <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Comment: Read my question. This forces my activity and application to be in landscape mode. I just want to put in landscape a specific view of my layout.

Comment: @screamingnoises, it only puts the Activity into landscape, not your app.

Comment: Well, if it changes the status bar to landscape, the app is in landscape for that activity. I don't want that. Nor I want the activity to recreate everything in landscape. I just want that view in specific to be in landscape. I'm not sure if it is possible, tomorrow I'll try to think on a better solution for this.